# Operator overloading in C++ - why do we need to pass parameter as const & (...)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, operator-overloading

let's say I want to overload an operator ==. I've got a class vector and the following method:

```
bool operator ==( const Vector & v )
{
    if(( this->x == v.x ) &&( this->y == v.y ) )
         return true;
    else
         return false;

}
```

Why do I need to pass an object (in this example v) as a constant address to this object? I know - const to force the programmer not to modify the passed object, but why &?

My second question concerns an operator overloading like +=, *= etc.
Please, look at this code:

```
Vector operator +( const Vector & v )
{
    return Vector( this->x + v.x, this->y + v.y );
}

// vs
Vector & operator +=( const Vector & v )
{
    this->x += v.x;
    this->y += v.y;
    return * this;
}
```

In the second case we can return a new object as well. Why do we return the same, incremented object?

Comment: A) so that you don't make a copy when you don't need one. B) So you can pass a derived type and get dynamic dispatch.

Comment: += returns a value to make it usable in the same way as the built in operators ("do as the ints do"). `a = (b += c)` is a valid if unusual usage.

Comment: They body of `operator==` can be simplified to `{ return x == v.x && y == v.y; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do that, it's just desirable to avoid needlessly copying an object.

For your second question, again you don't have to do that, but it makes += operate similarly for Vector as it does for int or double

Answer (score 1):

For the second question: If you write `a+=5;` or `a*=10;` you normally expect that the original variable a will be added to or multiplied... If you return original or new object is up to you, but you could confuse other colleagues if you use it counter-intuitively to original meaning...